# method not allowed, when using onlyajax in controller action

Tags: ajax, cakephp

**Background:**

I'm attempting to make good RESTful APIs in cakephp, and delegate front end work to a front end templating language Handlebars. As elicited here (http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/) , using the JsonView and making an extensionful api is a good approach.

**Problem:**

1. Allowing only ajax by using `$this->request->onlyAllow('ajax');` is returning method not allowed. I want to enforce this so my APIs are not directly called from the browser.
2. Could you (the community) validate my approach to building such APIs.

**Code:**

```
    //At the controller
        public function joinWithCode() {
                //$this->request->onlyAllow('ajax');  //returns 405 method not allowed
                //$this->request->onlyAllow('post'); //works and does not allow access from browser
                $this->response->type('json');
                $data = array(
                    'content' => 'something',
                    'error' => 'something else',
                );
                $this->set(compact('data'));
                $this->set('_serialize', 'data');
        }
//routes.php
Router::parseExtensions('json');
Router::connect('/Classrooms/join', array('controller' => 'classrooms', 'action' => 'joinWithCode'));
```

The post attempt from the postman extension:
[image: The post attempt from the postman extension]

Comment: Most likely you aren't actually sending an AJAX request, ie it lacks the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header... you should add a little more details of what your request actually looks like. ps. please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: @ndm thanks for the polite feedback and insight.